# How to create a thread of service or just a service in android which runs until the service is stopped explicitly?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I want a service which looks if Headphones are connected or not. If they are connected then do something & do something else while they are disconnected. I want the service or thread to run until it is stopped explicitly by pressing the stop button on it's activity.

Here is my `onStartCommand()` code & the code I want to run is in a function `theRun()`.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

 private final static String Headset_Flag = "android.intent.action.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG";

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand " + startId);
            theRun tR= new theRun();
            tR.start();
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }


private class theRun extends Thread
    {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
//                Log.i(TAG, "Service In Run " + currentId);
                try {
                    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

                    if (AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG.equals(Headset_Flag)) {

                        switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                Log.i(TAG, "Silent mode" + am.getRingerMode());
                                break;
                            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
                                Log.i(TAG, "Vibrate mode");
                                break;
                            case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
                                Log.i(TAG, "Normal mode");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch(Exception e){
                    String msg = e.getMessage();
                    msg.toString();
                }
            }


        };
    }
```

The service will only execute once on `onStartCommand()` if I insert my code there. But how to run a service or thread until it is explicitly stopped by Activity? Please guide me.

Comment: Architecturally, this would be better done by running in response to events, rather than trying to keep a sleeping (/ polling?) service process around.

Comment: I edited the post above, Can you tell me what does the if statement return? And how do I respond to events when I am only interested to whether the headphones are connected or not?

Comment: I doubt it does anything *useful* - you seem to be comparing two static values.  Try comparing the action of your Intent...

Comment: Would this help?
`Intent Headset_Flag = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG);`
`Headset_Flag.hasExtra("state");` @Chris Stratton

Answer (score 0):

return **START_STICKY** in **onStartCommand** method do this

try this

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
    theRun tR= new theRun();
    tR.start();
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample)

Comment: Note this doesn't actually mean it will keep running; rather it means that an attempt may be made to restart it if it prematurely stops.  There is no true support for permanently-running 3rd party services.